# How to detect if string contains any supplementary characters in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-16, surrogate-pairs, utf-32

From what I understand so far, [supplementary characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U.2B010000_to_U.2B10FFFF) (or "surrogate pairs") are defined in a range from `0xd800` to `0xdbff` for the first char, and from `0xdc00` and `0xdfff` for the second char.

So I'm trying to detect if an arbitrary string contains any such characters:

```
function isSupplementaryCharacter($c1, $c2)
{
    return $c1 >= 0xd800 && $c1 <= 0xdbff && $c2 >= 0xdc00 && $c2 <= 0xdfff;
}

function isStringWithSupplementaryCharacters($str)
{
    $ln = strlen($str);

    for($i = 0; $i < $ln - 1; $i++)
    {
        if(isSupplementaryCharacter(ord($str[$i]), ord($str[$i + 1])))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to detect them. For instance:

```
isStringWithSupplementaryCharacters("=!");
```

returns `false`.

So to test it, I wrote a small web page to see what codes those symbols become:

```
$txt = isset($_REQUEST['txt']) ? $_REQUEST['txt'] : '';
$htmTxt = htmlentities($txt);

$hex = '';
$ln = strlen($txt);
for($i = 0; $i < $ln; $i++)
{
    $hex .= dechex(ord($txt[$i])).", ";
}

$htmHex = htmlentities($hex);

echo <<<UUU01
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get">
<input type="text" name="txt"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>

<p>$htmTxt</p>
<p>$htmHex</p>

</body>
</html>
UUU01;
```

But the encoding I'm getting for  is not what I expected:

[image]

Why is it giving me `f0, 9f, 98, 8d` for it? Those don't fall within the definition above. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think php uses utf8 internally. The wikipedia link you provided is of utf-16

Comment: @peprumo oh, I see. So what's the encoding for those in UTF-8, do you know?

Comment: I don't know much, but according to [this](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/supplementary-test.html) it seems it should be all the unicode characters greater than U+FFFF

Comment: @peprumo hmm, so how do you detect it then? In UTF-8 it's just an array of bytes.

Comment: @peprumo: oh dude, you're right. Thanks. I need to do `mb_convert_encoding($txt, "utf-16", "utf-8")` on the string first.